# How to do a listener on every page load

Tags: struts

I'm trying to limit the session access to a Struts application so the users will only be able to use 1 tab at the time. To do this, I have to create an ID everytime a new page is loaded and assign that ID to the user's session. By doing so, if the user uses a page with a different ID than the one registered in his session, the action will be rejected.

How can I do a listener on every page load? Which interface should I use?

Or do you have any other idea of how I could manage multiple tabs?

I'm Using Struts 1 and Java 4.

Comment: Probably a custom request processor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring MVC [Interceptors](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) and override the preHandle method.

Returning false inside should cancel your request for not allowed additional tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interceptor to do this. You will need to define it on your interceptor stack in your struts.xml and code the interceptor to check the JEE role information provided by your web application server. The interceptor can be coded to give a redirect result on the other tab if there was recently an action called however you will probably need to coordinate it via JS generated ids and AJAX.

https://struts.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html